# Block Metro App with GPO - Software Restriction Policy

Tags: group-policy

So I know how to block an app via Software Restriction Policies >> Path and it works for files inside Program Files and System32.

What I want is to block the Metro Calculator via GPO >> Software Restriction Policy.

I found a folder under C:\Program Files\WindowsApps and blocked

number.exe but no luck.

Any Thoughts?

I do not want to use AppLocker as I have been told by Admin to use Software Restriction Policies.

Example: [Software Restriction Policy Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GL6Xm.gif)

Comment: you can only block older software with SRP - you would need to use the modern technology (APPLOCKER) "AppLocker is a new feature in Windows Server 2008 R2 and Windows 7 that advances the features and functionality of Software Restriction Policies. AppLocker contains new capabilities and extensions that allow you to create rules to allow or deny applications from running based on unique identities of files and to specify which users or groups can run those applications. " https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh994606.aspx

Comment: I'd ask your admin how the windows xp/2003 technology isn't outdated.

Comment: Well I did some reading [Applocker vs Software restriction policy @ Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/questions/447078/applocker-vs-software-restriction-policy) and found that helpful, I don't think what I was asked to do is possible, I am only able to block the store via SRP, but I will accept your answer since it is the best option (and only!) Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use a packaged app rule, you cannot block an executable you need to block the application

Comment: you mean for store apps? Because blocking executable via path is the only way I have blocked applications as of now. Could you elaborate a bit on packaged app rules? I read the only way to block store apps is via blocking the entire store, which is not what I am after, just a specific store app.

Comment: See https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh831350.aspx

Comment: This is Applocker, I want to use Software Restriction Policies  >> see https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2008.06.srp.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You must create an "Allow" rule and Allow All Metro Apps Via Publisher (select any app and slide enforcement rules to publishers) and add an exception for the App you wish to Block via Package name.

Detailed guide [Here](https://www.freesoftwareservers.com/index.php/2015/12/01/block-specific-metro-app-with-applocker-packaged-app-rules/)